# How to remove and copy part of deque in c++

Tags: c++, deque

I want to get the part of deque into other deque and remove that part from orignal without much processing, so that i can operate on the sub part deque in case of multithreaded programing

Comment: Not sure exactly why this question got downvoted but you can surely improve its reading by adding the current code you have, what you tried and by making it a non-one-liner question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the iterators for the section of the `deque` you want, You can instanciate another `deque` with that.

You can also use the `std::deque::erase` idiom to remove those elements from the original `deque`.

Comment: Plain `std::deque::erase` will do, if you have the iterators.